# Можно улучшить этот код?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void file_read(string name) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(name.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        const int size = 100;
        char tab[size];
        char sign;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            tab[i] = 0;
        }
        int max = 0;
        int id = 0;
        while (file >> sign)
        {
            tab[sign - 32]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < sign; i++)
        {
            if (max < tab[i])
            {
                id = i;
                max = tab[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "The most common frequent sign: " << char(id + 32) << ". It shows us " << max << " times";
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error";
    }
}

int main()
{
    string nameFile;
    cout << "Enter name of file: ";
    cin >> nameFile;
    file_read(nameFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, когда говорите улучшить? Читаемость, производительность?

Comment: производительность

Comment: Что ваша программа делает?

Comment: считает знаки в текстовом файле и показывает какой из них самый частый

Comment: @KonstantyPierog даже если можно то на уровне погрешности, код уже оптимизирован вашим компилятором. Возможно даст какой-либо эффект использование Win API для чтения файла.

Answer (score 1):

Начну с неприятного - авторский код не работает нормально. Не учитывает пробелы, не в состоянии работать с русскими буквами, цикл `for (int i = 0; i < sign; i++)` совершенно непонятный etc etc.

Если кто-то его с помощью напильника доведет до ума, можем сравнить с моим -

```
void file_read(const string& name) {
    ifstream file(name.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        int tab[256] = {0};
        int mx = 0;
        char mc;

        file.seekg(0,istream::end);
        string buf;
        buf.resize(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0);
        file.read(&buf[0],buf.size());
        for(char c: buf)
        {
            if (int z = ++tab[(unsigned char)c]; mx < z)
            {
                mx = z;
                mc = c;
            };
        }
        cout << "The most common frequent char: " << mc 
             << ". It shows us " << mx << " times";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Или написать `int tab[256]{0};`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да, почему-то не подумал. Но я сейчас в очень расстроенных чувствах...

Comment: @Harry Вообще ваш код по факту просто выглядит лучше) ничего особо не изменилось. Вот интересно не быстрей ли будет читать весь файл сразу или  например использовать буффер?

Comment: сам не знаю честно говоря

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, быстрее всего будет, если использовать [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если насчет производительности, то вот прямо сегодня я посимвольно работал с потоками.
Могу сказать следующее:
while (file >> sign)
лучше переписать на использование С библиотеки. И использовать _getc_nolock

FILE* f = ...
char ch = _getc_nolock(f);;
for (;;)
{
count++; //вставьте сюда вашу обработку

```
    ch = _getc_nolock(f);
    if (ch == EOF)
        break;      
}
```

Увеличение производительности в моей проге в десять раз.
Если надо кровь из носу iostream, то можно не >> попробовать, а get(ch).

```
    unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int pos = 0;
char ch;
cin.get(ch); // не cin, а свой поток поставьте
for (;;)
{
    count++;
    cin.get(ch);
    if (cin.eof())
        break;
    pos++;
}
```